# Having Issues with Flexbox and sizing elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I've made a neat little prime number generator  and I'm trying to get it to look nice.  The idea is that I have half the screen as the input, and the other side as output.

```css
body{
  background-color: #F5E9E2;
  color: #0B0014;
  display:flex;
}
.inputSide{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50vw;
  justify-content: center;
}
.inputDiv{
  width: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color:#E3B5A4;
}
.outputSide{
  width: 50vw;
  display: flex;
  height: 25 px;
}
```

(https://codepen.io/seth-alan-burleson/pen/NWRNLOG?editors=1111)
I've taken out most of the extra stuff as I'm trying to just fix these elements at the moment.  I'm also using React for frontend rendering if that matters.

The issue arises when you put a larger number in for the maximum (lets say 1000+) the page turns very ugly.  I'd like for the input side to at least stay the same, and possibly have the output side scale the font size down or be scrollable.  I'm just not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: You could set a variable to hold your window height at document load, then compare the window.innerHeight after the code has generated the prime numbers, if it is larger then run code to reduce the size of your font...

Comment: Consider adding the results to a label that scrolls the contents when it overflows.